# How to start 2 times winform and read different ID`s from same file in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

first of all I want to apologize about Title.

I have one winform which make post requests reading from text file line by line through 1-200. I want to put one textbox on form and when I run second time to write in this textbox from which line to start reading.

For example:
I run my app and start read and post from 1-200. 
Then I start second time app and put in textbox 100 and start reading same file from line 100-200.

Comment: How many lines does your text file count?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few lines, so you can use this code.
It's not the best, but it's easy

```
int skip_count = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text) - 1;
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(your_file_path)
                     .Skip(skip_count)
                     .Take(200 - skip_count)
                     .ToArray();
```

Note that you MUST check textbox input... mine is just an easy example...

**UPDATED after OP comment:**

```
int skip_count;
if (!Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out skip_count))
    skip_count = 0;
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(your_file_path)
                     .Skip(skip_count)
                     .Take(200 - skip_count)
                     .ToArray();
```

You could also check `KeyDown` textbox event and accept only digits...

Comment: If you use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` it will at least avoid reading the skipped lines into memory. But it will be a touch slower.

Comment: @yamen: `File` doesn't have any `ReadLines` method... am I missing something?

Comment: Does in .NET 4+, and it returns an `IEnumerable<string>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: @Marco can you give me some example to check for input in textbox ?

Comment: @yamen: yes, you're right, sorry... I didn't notice I was using framework 3.5... lol

Comment: I can`t get this to work. Where i should put this in textbox event or in cicle wheee i read file?

Comment: @JasonPaddle: my example works when you put something in textbox and press a button (for example) to start reading: file will be read and starting linex according to textbox text will be skipped...

Comment: @Marco: i tried and started two times app. First time without put anything. Second app i put from 100 to 200 but read whole file again not from 100 to 200 only..

Comment: @JasonPaddle: do you want to get always rown up to 200? Is fo, take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: @Marco may be my question is not good at first place. I start the program and hit button "start" and read whole file. Then i want to start second time the program and put in textbox some number of ID(15,139...etc)and program start read from this number that i input to end of file..

Comment: Yes, the file always will round up to some specific number. Still read whole file instead of number that i input from where to start.

Comment: @JasonPaddle: did you changed your code with mine? Did you notice I put `.Take(200 - skip_count)`? This part takes rows up to 200 starting from the number you have in your textbox... it's impossible you still get the whole file...

Comment: Yes, i noticed when you edit your comment and i changed code also. May be i didn`t put in the right place the code..

Comment: @JasonPaddle: no, probably you're mixing code... I really don't know why... I've just tried and it works perfectly...

Comment: @Marco i have one foreach where i turning the file and i put this piece of code.

Comment: @JasonPaddle: edit your question and show us the code you're using, telling us what do you want to do and what's going wrong.

Comment: @Marco your example is ok. I just have other problem that i can`t run same app second time. every post i write in log file and second instance of app cant write in log file